# display element based on comparison operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem with comparison operator, in my forum i want to show an element if the number of post is <= 10, <=50 and so on....but if <=50 is displayed i want to hide <=10.

My code:

```
if (userPosts  <= 10){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-baby autopost"/> less than 10 posts</span>
        );
      }
      if (userPosts  <= 50){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-child autopost"/> less than 50 posts</span>
        );
      }
      if (userPosts  <= 100){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn autopost"/> less than 100 posts</span>
        );
      }
```

the problem is that if a user have 200 posts, i see all of these 3 elements displayed, and i want to display only <=100 instead.

Comment: Looks like you've got the logic the wrong way round: x <= y means x is less than or equal to y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a double condition in your `if` statement :

```
if (userPosts  <= 10){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-baby autopost"/> less than 10 posts</span>
        );
      }
      if (userPosts  <= 50 && userPosts > 10){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-child autopost"/> less than 50 posts</span>
        );
      }
      if (userPosts  <= 100 && userPosts > 50){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn autopost"/> less than 100 posts</span>
        );
      }
```

EDIT or use `else if` statement :

```
if (userPosts  <= 10){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-baby autopost"/> less than 10 posts</span>
        );
      }
      else if (userPosts  <= 50){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-child autopost"/> less than 50 posts</span>
        );
      }
      else if (userPosts  <= 100){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn autopost"/> less than 100 posts</span>
        );
      }
```

Comment: thats works pretty fine! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `else-if` block as:

```
if (userPosts  <= 10){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-baby autopost"/> less than 10 posts</span>
        );
      }
     else if (userPosts  <= 50){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-child autopost"/> less than 50 posts</span>
        );
      }
      else if (userPosts  <= 100){
        vnode.children.push(
          <span className="auto-badge"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn autopost"/> less than 100 posts</span>
        );
      }
```